# How do I create a session context in next js 13?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I'm using Next Js 13 with api authentication using jwt. I am wondering how can I create a sessionprovider context like it is in Next-Auth and wrap my `(dashboard)/layout.tsx` with it?

This is `api/auth/sign-in/route.ts`

```
import { connect } from '@/db/config';
import { NextResponse, NextRequest } from 'next/server';
import User from '@/models/userModel';
import bcryptjs from 'bcryptjs';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

connect();

export async function POST(req: NextRequest) {
  try {
    const reqBody = await req.json();
    const { email, password } = reqBody;

    //check if user exists
    const user = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (!user) {
      return NextResponse.json(
        { error: 'No such user found!' },
        { status: 400 }
      );
    }

    //check if the password is correct
    const validPassword = await bcryptjs.compare(password, user.password);
    if (!validPassword) {
      return NextResponse.json({ error: 'Invalid password!' }, { status: 400 });
    }
    //create token data
    const tokenData = {
      id: user._id,
      firstname: user.firstname,
      lastname: user.lastname,
      email: user.email,
      isAdmin: user.isAdmin
    };
    //create token
    const token = await jwt.sign(tokenData, process.env.JWT_SECRET!, {
      expiresIn: '12h'
    });

    const response = NextResponse.json({
      message: 'login successful',
      success: true
    });
    response.cookies.set('token', token, { httpOnly: true });
    return response;
  } catch (error: any) {
    return NextResponse.json({ error: error.message }, { status: 500 });
  }
}
```

This is working fine with component level api call, but I want this to be called with a context function at componet level where I can get the user from the session and actual active session. And I would like to wrap my `(dashboard)/layout.tsx` with the e.g `SessionProvider` context.

I tried this after asking chat gpt what to do but I still can't get it working:

```
'use client';
import React, { createContext, useState, useContext } from 'react';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';

interface UserData {
  userId: string;
  email: string;
}

// Define the context type
interface SessionContextType {
  user: UserData | null;
  login: (email: string, password: string) => void;
  logout: () => void;
}

// Create the context
const SessionContext = createContext<SessionContextType>({
  user: null,
  login: () => {},
  logout: () => {}
});

export function useSession() {
  return useContext(SessionContext);
}

export function SessionProvider({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [user, setUser] = useState<UserData | null>(null);

  const login = async (email: string, password: string) => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.post('/api/auth/sign-in', user);
      router.push('/dashboard');
      if (res.data) {
        const data = await res.data;
        const token = data.token;
        // Decode the token to get user data and set the user state
        const decodedToken: any = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET!);
        setUser(decodedToken);
      } else {
        // Handle login error, show error message, etc.
        console.error('Login failed:', res.status);
      }
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.log('Login failed', error.message);
    }
  };

  const logout = () => {
    setUser(null);
  };

  return (
    <SessionContext.Provider value={{ user, login, logout }}>
      {children}
    </SessionContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: + same here, save the post for learning

Comment: Why not just use the session provider from NextAuth? If you simply want to authenticate the user and see if they are logged in then NextAuth would save you a lot of development time. Seems like you're trying to recreate the wheel by making your own context provider for session.